# Соединение округлых площадей

Tags: html, css, css3, svg, css-animation

Как мне создать логотип,  в соответствии с прикрепленным ниже изображением.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это то, что я создал:  [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/60jnk66d/16/)

Основная проблема заключается в том, - как можно соединить два блока с фигурой, как показано на рисунке ниже.
Может кто-нибудь, пожалуйста, предложить, как это сделать?

```css
body,html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  background-color: #efefef;
}
.wrapper {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -22.5px;
  margin-left: -22.5px;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  position: relative;
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
ul li {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  position: absolute;
  /*animation: dance 888ms infinite alternate;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0.5, 1);*/
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  animation: dance 888ms infinite alternate;
}
.block-1 {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #0076aa;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.block-2 {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #98bd81;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.block-3 {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #98bd81;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.block-4 {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #0076aa;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <ul class='blocks'>
    <li class='block-1'></li>
    <li class='block-2'></li>
    <li class='block-3'></li>
    <li class='block-4'></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Перевод вопроса: [Connecting rounded squares  @Sanjeev K](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39894660/7394871)

Comment: ассоциация:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39894660/connecting-rounded-squares/39895104#39895104

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Учитывая трудности выравнивания и создания двойных кривых с помощью CSS, это, очевидно, работа для SVG. Кривые намного легче создавать и контролировать. Вот пример использования:

- Inline SVG
- [quadratic bezier curves](https://svg-art.ru/?page_id=914#comm_Quadratic)
- [transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Basic_Transformations)
- Элемент [use](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use), поэтому есть только одно вхождение тега `path`

```css
svg{ display:block; width:40%; margin:0 auto;}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 16 15">
  <defs>
    <path id="shape" d="M7 0 H10 Q11 0 11 1 V4 Q11 5 10 5 H7 Q5 5 5 7 V9 Q5 10 4 10 H1 Q0 10 0 9 V6 Q0 5 1 5 H4 Q6 5 6 3 V1 Q6 0 7 0z" />
  </defs>
  <use xlink:href="#shape" fill="#0076AA"/>
  <use xlink:href="#shape" fill="#98BD81" transform="translate(5,5)"/>
</svg>
```

### C анимацией прелоудера

```css
svg{ display:block; width:40%; margin:0 auto;}
.sq{ animation: opacity .6s infinite alternate; }
.gr{ animation-delay:-.6s;}
@keyframes opacity { to {opacity: 0;} }
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 16 15">
  <defs>
    <path id="shape" d="M7 0 H10 Q11 0 11 1 V4 Q11 5 10 5 H7 Q5 5 5 7 V9 Q5 10 4 10 H1 Q0 10 0 9 V6 Q0 5 1 5 H4 Q6 5 6 3 V1 Q6 0 7 0z" />
  </defs>
  <use class="sq bl" xlink:href="#shape" fill="#0076AA"/>
  <use class="sq gr" xlink:href="#shape" fill="#98BD81" transform="translate(5,5)"/>
</svg>
```

Обратите внимание, что вам нужно будет добавить префиксы поставщиков в анимацию, и что анимация элементов svg не поддерживается IE / Edge.
Перевод ответа: [Connecting rounded squares @web-tiki](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39895104/7394871)